# How to generate Input number of input fields depending on the number of data in a javascript object

Tags: javascript

I am new to programming and have come across a bit of an issue. In javascript I have the object with the data:

```js
const year2021 = {
'year': 2021,
'season': 'winter',
'edition': ['2000', '2021'],
'price': ['0.14', '0.15'],
'total': ['140', '150'],
}

console.log(year2021)
```

How can I generate input field for the edition price and total dynamically? To clarify I need to create generate the input fields for each input data, regardless if it is 1, 2 or ten. I need them to be generated dynamically.

Comment: does data at same index link ? edition 2000 is link to price 0.14 and total = 140 ?

Comment: To clarify, edition, price and total all have their own input fields. the div has three columns that have input fields in them. edition has input field that will have edition data and so on. I can put 2000 for example in one input field, but I need to be able to generate these input fields automatically in each column.